# Using a settings file other than settings.py in Django

Tags: django

I want to use a different settings file in django -- specifically settings_prod -- yet whenever I try to do a syncdb with `--settings=settings_prod`, it complains:

```
python2.6 manage.py syncdb  --settings=settings_prod
Error: Can't find the file 'settings.py' in the directory containing 'manage.py'. It appears you've customized things.
You'll have to run django-admin.py, passing it your settings module.
(If the file settings.py does indeed exist, it's causing an ImportError somehow.)
```

I've also tried setting the environment variable `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=settings_prod` to no end.

Edit: I have also set the environment variable in my wsgi file, also to no end:

```
import os
import sys

from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'project.settings_prod'
application = WSGIHandler()
```

Suggestions?

Comment: And with the WSGI is it working correctly? I had this problem before, but only with `manage.py`

Comment: I think so, because it's at least displaying a URL that I set. I just can't get it to syncdb.

Comment: Ok, someone just answered what I had in mind:). `import settings` is hardcoded in `manage.py` so no luck with this simple approach.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I do know that no matter what you do with `manage.py`, you're going to get that error because `manage.py` does a relative import of `settings`:

```
try:
    import settings # Assumed to be in the same directory.
```

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-option---settings

> Note that this option is unnecessary
>   in manage.py, because it uses
>   settings.py from the current project
>   by default.

You should try `django-admin.py syncdb --settings=mysettings` instead

Comment: I have tried that, but I get: `ImportError: Could not import settings 'settings_prod' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named settings_prod` -- but it should be, according to my WSGI file

Comment: Well, actually I just modified the WSGI file to include this: `sys.path.append("/home/username/webapps/django/project")`, but still no bueno.

Comment: try passing the --pythonpath argument to django-admin.py to ensure that your path is set up correctly.

Comment: Regardless of what your WSGI config file says, if you're running django-admin.py your settings file has to be on the pythonpath _now_, not when your WSGI handler is called by Apache. You could for example edit your manage.py file and do the appropriate `sys.path` modifications and change the hard coded `import settings` to `import mysettings as settings`

Answer (score 25):

Try creating a `settings` module.

1. Make a `settings` folder in the same directory as `manage.py`.
2. Put your different settings files in that folder (e.g. `base.py` and `prod.py`).
3. Make `__init__.py` and import whatever settings you want to use as your default. For example, your `__init__.py` file might look like this:

   ```
   from base import *
   ```
4. Run your project and override the settings:

   ```
   $ python2.6 manage.py syncdb --settings=settings.prod
   ```

Answer (score 4):

this works for me:

```
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=config.settings.abc python manage.py migrate
```

Answer (score 1):

this will help you:

- create a another file "setting_prod.py" with your original settings.py file.
- write down your setting which you need to run, in setting_prod.py file.
- Then import setting_prod.py file in your settings.py file.

for ex. 
settings.py:

```
VARIABLE = 1

import setting_prod
```

setting_prod.py

```
VARIABLE = 2
```

After importing setting_prod.py file in settings.py file, VARIABLE will set to new value to "2" from "1".

Comment: why you have .py in the end? I've got error `ImportError: No module named py` and VARIABLE string won't be replaced as you want. If you'll have `import setting_prod` it will be as setting_prod.VARIABLE

Comment: If you set 
  
    `from setting_prod import *`

You will get the behavior you are looking for but, it is less pythonic.

Answer (score 0):

We can use this method to set different settings file, for example, I use different settings file for my unit test (settings_unit_test.py). Also I do have other settings file for different infrastructure environment settings_dev.py, settings_test.py and settings_prod.py.

In windows environment(same can done in linux as well)

```
set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=settings_unit_test
set PYTHONPATH=<path_of_your_directory_where_this_file_'settings_unit_test.py'_is_kept>
```