# Is there a way to mention the database settings while starting the Django app?

Tags: django

From the docs, it looks like the database needs to be present in the settings.py. Is there a way to pass the database details while running `python manage.py runserver` given the migrations have been completed?

Edit -

Use case - The database is not known beforehand so I can't have it hardcoded in settings.py. Also, there will be one database for the entire app.

2. [Using a settings file other than settings.py in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466571/using-a-settings-file-other-than-settings-py-in-django) - This questions answers how to use a settings file different than settings.py. However, I am looking for ways in which I don't use settings file to specify the database credentials.

Comment: Can you specify the use case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a settings file other than settings.py in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466571/using-a-settings-file-other-than-settings-py-in-django)

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: you can use environment variables to store the passwords and use with os.environ['DJANGO_PASSWORD']

Answer (score 1):

split your settings.py into two files

- base_settings.py (add all the common settings here)
- development.py
  (add your database settings here)

like :

```
from .base_settings import *

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'XX.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'XX',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'ATOMIC_REQUESTS':True,
        'PASSWORD': '*****',
        'HOST': '0.0.0.0',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

and run your project using

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8002 --settings=django_project_name.development
```

Comment: If I could pass arguments to the development.py(or base_settings.py), then that would be the best solution since I will not have to modify the files at runtime.

Comment: try if you can set a .json file as config file and read the values of it.